# Passing key to next activity

Tags: android, firebase, mvp

I'm developing an application with the MVP architecture. I have a `RecyclerView` with the following method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatRoomAdapter.ChatRoomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mChatRooms.get(position).getUid();

        }
    });
}
```

I need to pass the `mChatRooms.get(position).getUid()` to the next acitivty/presenter/interactor but how can I cleanly do this? Can I use an intent using the `putExtra` method to pass the data?

Comment: Using Intent is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like

```
interface YourPresenter {
   void onItemClicked(int uid);
}

class YourPresenterImpl : YourPresenter {

   @Override
   void onItemClicked(int uid) {
       view.startActivity(uid) // method from your interface for you view
   }
}
```

and then you must add your presenter's reference to you item click in holder